# Unitary matrix of polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices, matrix-analysis

I know unitary matrix of polar decomposition ($A=UP$; $U$ is unitary and $P$ is positive semi-definite) cannot be unique (but $P$ is!) if $A$ is not invertible.
Can you give some examples that $A=UP=U_2P$ where $U_2$ is another unitary matrix different to $U$? Is there any formal relationship between $U$ and $U_2$?

Comment: $U$ and $U_2$ must agree on the range of $P$ and are otherwise arbitrary. For example, if $A=0$, then any $U$ will work.